# Retrieving image dimensions using image-size, and adding these values to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm fairly new to Node JS, so I'm probably doing it completely wrong!

I have created an upload form to upload images. I have got this working, and the images are being uploaded to a folder within the public folder.

My next step is to get the width and height of the images. I have used the image-size module and have managed to get the width and height.

I would like to add the width and height to an object I have created, however I can't seem to figure out how to add these values to the object. The object is then used to add data about the image to a database.

````
    uploadImages(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {

            console.log("Error:", err.message)

        } else {

            const imagesArray = req.files.map((image) => {

                let imageObject = {}

                imageObject.type = image.mimeType
                imageObject.path = image.path
                imageObject.link = image.path.replace("public", "").replace(/\\/g, "/")
                imageObject.timeUploaded = Date.now()

                sizeOf("public/" + imageObject.link, (err, sizes) => {

                    if(err) {
                        error(err)
                    } else {
                        success(sizes)
                    }
                })

                const error = (err) => {

                    console.log(err)

                }

                const success = (data) => {

                    imageObject.width = data.width
                    imageObject.height = data.height

                    console.log(imageObject)

                }

                return imageObject

            })


            db.collection("uploadtest2").insertMany(imagesArray, (err, result) => {

                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                }

                // db.collection("resized-images").insertMany()

                console.log("something saved to the database")

            })

        }
    })

    res.redirect("/")
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try is js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/wy7omr6k/5/

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;

alert('height: '+height+' Width:'+width);
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQHiNSL4Or29cg/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=0e00tehBFFtuqgUCfAijpOkoBl89jxOTIe_k9HHpi_4" />
```